# Brightness control keys don't work on Lenovo Y540 but xrandr does

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lenovo, brightness

I recently bought a Lenovo Legion Y540, and most options work except for the brightness control keys, the computer starts with 100% brightness and the keys (F5 and F6) seemingly do nothing, the brightness pop-up also does not show up. I have found that the following command seems to work
`xrandr --output DP-4 --brightness 0.6` to lower the brightness. 
I tried setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"` in the GRUB settings but that did not help things either. I did the installation with `nouveau.modeset=0` and I do remember the keys to be working. Its after installing nvidia drivers that this problem seems to have risen (not absolutely sure). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem (Y540 with nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 19.04), but for me the brightness pop-ups does show up, and the slider changes the value but the actual brightness does not change.

Answer (score 4):

I have This Issue with **Lenovo Y540** that comes with **NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660Ti** Graphics Card

Ubuntu version: **19.10**

Also, I have upgraded to version **20.04** and working fine

you need to edit or create this file

`sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf`

and add this line

`Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1;"`

after this line `Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"`

so the file **10-nvidia.conf** will look like this:

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1;"  # Line need to be added
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

and **save** the **restart** your laptop

and the brightness control keys will work

Answer (score 1):

Setting the bios to switchable graphics works for me (y540 with gtx1650). Also setting "acpi_backlight=intel_backlight" as kernel option works but also seems to mess with resume from suspend.