# Login screen changed

Tags: login-screen, wayland, protocol

I've a problem with my laptop in brightness after installation of NVIDIA card. I followed this 
[Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170044/brightness-control-keys-dont-work-on-lenovo-y540-but-xrandr-does) and when i restart laptop and login again it worked only with way-land
and when i tried to use any command i got

```
No protocol specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts to fix it .. i found that i can choose it from `software&updates` then choose `X.org` to `login` with normal way 
[image]